# VB macro to merge to data set based on several conditions via an array

Tags: vba, excel

Description: there are two worksheets, one of them is used as a file with the original data set (master data) and the second of which correspond to updates to the original data. The master file is the size in A1: L, where the first row stands for names. The update file data is in the range: A1: Q, where the first row again corresponds to the column names.
In column D of the update file there are items numbers (ID) which correspond to IDs in column G of the master File in unspecified order. In the column Q of the update file, there are three criteria: price, text, text and price. In column B of the update file, there are two criteria: delete and update.

My Task Steps:

Step 1: The macro finds a match between the two: column D in the update file and column G in the main file.

Step 2: If there is match in step 1, the macro checks the column B value:

- if the cell contain is “delete”, then in column L of the main file in the corresponding to the found match cell, insert the date value (as defined in the variable: vDato).

Step 3: If the cell contain is “update”, so go to the column Q of the update file and proceed based on:

- If the cell value is “text”, so do not do anything (exit)
- If the cell value is “price” or “text and price”, then add a row after the found matching items number and copy-paste the value of the price from the column O from the update worksheet to the cell in column I in the master sheet.

Challenge: Both files about 30.000 rows down, so the macro has to proceed via arrays. First, I tried to input ranges into arrays and work with IF statements via looping, yet, macro runs but nothing is happening. Then, I tried to merge two arrays in a new worksheet, which again contains some mistakes.

My first macro:

```
Sub OpdatereArkEfterNyInfo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lCol As Long, X As Long
    Dim opdTabel As Variant, hovTabel As Variant
    Dim arOutputUp(), arOutputH()
    Dim vDato As Variant, Varer As Variant, PrisTekst As Variant
    vDato = InputBox("Angiv opdateringsdatoen", "Identifikator")
    If Len(vDato) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    opdTabel = Sheets("update").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'ReDim arOutputUp(1 To UBound(opdTabel), 1 To UBound(opdTabel))
    'opdTabel = Sheets("update").Range("A1:Q" & Sheets("update").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
     hovTabel = Sheets("Compliance2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'ReDim arOutputH(1 To UBound(hovTabel), 1 To UBound(hovTabel))
    'hovTabel = Sheets("Compliance2").Range("A1:N" & Sheets("Compliance2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
    X = 1
    For i = 2 To UBound(opdTabel)
        For j = 2 To UBound(hovTabel)
            If (opdTabel(i, 4) = hovTabel(j, 7)) Then
                If (opdTabel(i, 2) = "delete") Then
                    hovTabel(j, 12) = vDato
                    If (opdTabel(i, 2) = "update") Then
                        If (opdTabel(i, 17) = "tekst") Then
                            Exit For
                            If (opdTabel(i, 17) = "pris") Or (opdTabel(i, 17) = "Tekst og pris") Then 
                                Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert
                                hovTabel(j + 1, 9) = opdTabel(i, 15) And vDato = hovTabel(j + 1, 11)
                                For lCol = 1 To UBound(hovTabel)
                                    arOutputH(X, lCol) = hovTabel(i, lCol)
                                Next
                                X = X + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
           End If
        Next
    Next

    If X = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No IDs are matched"
    End If
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "test"
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arOutputH), UBound(arOutputH, 2)) = arOutputH 
End Sub
```

In my second macro, I tried to defined to arrays and merge them based on ID in both data sets; however, the code didn't make matching part at all.

Ok, I have found how to add the other code .
After proceeding the structure, my code looks like:

```
Sub Plan_Main()
    Dim WsMaster, WbUpdate, vDato As Variant
    Dim i, j, k As Long

    WsMaster = Sheets("WsMaster").Range("A1:Q" & Sheets("WsMaster").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
    WbUpdate = Sheets("WbUpdate").Range("A1:N" & Sheets("WbUpdate").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)

    vDato = InputBox("Insert date of update", "Identificator")
    If Len(vDato) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    k = 1
    For i = 2 To UBound(WbUpdate)
        For j = 2 To UBound(WsMaster)
          If (WbUpdate(j, 4) = WsMaster(i, 7)) Then
            'If there is a match Then
                If (WbUpdate(i, 2) = "delete") Then
                ' If Update.Column(B) = "Delete"
                ' Let WsMaster.Column(L) = vDato
                    WsMaster(j, 12) = vDato
                    ' If Update.Column(B) is "Update"
                    If (WbUpdate(j, 2) = "update") Then
                        ' If Update.Column(Q) = "Price" Or "Text and price"
                            If (WbUpdate(i, 17) = "Price" Or "Text og Price") Then
                            ' Add row in WsMaster below matched row - here I am not aware af how I proceed with adding a row
                              Sheets("WsMaster").Range("A:Q" & Sheets("WsMaster").Range("A:Q").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1) = WbUpdate(i, 15)
                              ' Copy price from WsUpdate.Column(O) to WsMaster.Column(I) in the new row
                               WsMaster.Range("I" & j.Row) = WbUpdate.Range("O" & i.Row).Offset(1, 0)
                              'If Update.Column(Q) = "Text"
                              If (WbUpdate(i, 17) = "Text") Then
                               ' do nothing
                                Exit For
                                k = k + 1
                              End If
                            End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' If there is no match Then
    If k = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No Match is found"
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your planning is both imprecise and incomplete, and it doesn't attempt to meet your requirements. Your requirement is to cut the task into tasks that you can manage step by step after small step. So, this is what your plan should look like:-

```
Sub Plan_Main()

    ' Open the Master workbook = Activeworkbook (containing the code) = WbMaster
    ' Open the Update workbook = WbUpdate

    ' Name the Master worksheet = WsMaster
    ' Name the Update worksheet = WsUpdate

    ' Loop through all items in Update, start with row 2

        ' Take the value in column D
        ' Look for a match in WsMaster.Column(G)
        ' If there is a match Then
            ' If Update.Column(B) = "Delete"
                ' Let WsMaster.Column(L) = WsUpdate.Column(??)
            ' If Update.Column(B) is "Update"
                ' If Update.Column(Q) = "Price" Or "Text and price"
                    ' Add row in WsMaster below matched row
                    ' Copy price from WsUpdate.Column(O) to WsMaster.Column(??) in the new row
                ' If Update.Column(Q) = "Text"
                    ' do nothing

        ' If there is no match Then
End Sub
```

Start by filling in the parts which aren't clear to me or were not defined by you. Then start translating thought into code, line by line. If it gets too hard, split a line of words into several. If you know what you want to say and don't know the expression to use come to this website. Lots of people here want to help.

Comment: Hey, thank you for pointing out to my issue - appreciate any help. I tried to proceed according to the structure and found difficulty with adding the entire row exactly after the found match Item-ID and copy paste method. It doesn't seem difficult, but I simply don't know how to do this. I am attaching my code below, could you get a look at this, please?

Comment: Sub Plan_Main()

Dim WsMaster, WbUpdate, vDato As Variant
Dim i, j, k As Long

' Open the Master workbook = Activeworkbook (containing the code) = WbMaster
' Open the Update workbook = WbUpdate
' Name the Master worksheet = WsMaster
' Name the Update worksheet = WsUpdate
WsMaster = Sheets("WsMaster").Range("A1:Q" & Sheets("WsMaster").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
WbUpdate = Sheets("WbUpdate").Range("A1:N" & Sheets("WbUpdate").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)
   
vDato = InputBox("Insert date of update", "Identificator")
If Len(vDato) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Comment: How can I insert the macro code again in a proper way her?  It doesn't look grate.

Comment: I think the idea is to modify your question and/or ask a new one. But most of all, you need to take much smaller steps. Why not deal with the first one of the plan. The way you go, you now want to define a worksheet (2 worksheets, in fact), but you haven't defined a workbook yet. How can you have a worksheet without having a workbook?

Comment: You also made a logical mistake in dimensioning. Dim i, j, k As Long defines I and j as Variants. The correct line would be Dim I As Long, j As Long, k As Long, but using descriptive names will be of greater help to you and putting each variable in its own line will help you avoid mistakes of this kind.

Comment: I attempted to insert my macro by editing my original question. Yet, with some mislapses, but it is readable at least.

Comment: Since the idea of the updating is to pull new data from the ERS system into a worksheet, and  copy-paste this in my Master data to make ongoing update, so I don't need definding workbook - my marko is in the modul of my only master data.

Comment: In that case, true, the code can work with defaults, but for you it will be easier (clearer) to define a workbook. For me it is absolutely necessary because I can't find the other one you mentioned in your description. If you like to follow my plan then the first line translates into Dim wbMaster As Workbook Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook. Note that this is different from your code because your code will work on the ActiveWorkbook, meaning it might run on a workbook other than the one containing the code. Next the WbUpdate should be dimensioned and set on the same fashion.